# Ubuntu Touch porting: bad file tree

Tags: android, ubuntu-touch, porting

I'm trying to port ubuntu touch to Samsung Galaxy S Plus but I'm finding it really difficult. The problems at first were to find a good CM rom as base, because this device is not officially supported by CM. Currently I'm using EhndroixIII but now I'm founding a lot of problems with the porting guide. In particular my file tree seems totally different from the one of the guide. For example, there is no device folder. What can I do to solve? Should I create those files?

My repository is https://github.com/fcole90/utouch-sgsp.git

Comment: have you reached any thing interesting with your project? there was a thread on xda but then the developer gave up so I'm hoping to find someone else who have reached further.

Answer (score 0):

The repository posted does not contain sources but the actual installed file system mangled into a git repository.

I have followed http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Unofficial_Ports#Samsung_Galaxy_S_Plus_.28GT-I9001.29 to fine a set of git repositories on which you can base on in https://github.com/skywalker01

The bad news is that the Galaxy S Plus is based out of gingerbread and our Ubuntu Touch code base is based out of jellybean+, which means more work than just following the generic porting guide would need to happen.

Comment: I don't think so because I tried many JB ports for I9001: CyanogenMod, AOKP, Ehndroix III. So if I had the correct sources I could do something. At the moment I found the following:
https://github.com/ivendor

https://github.com/arco

https://github.com/skywalker01/android_device_samsung_ariesve

https://github.com/doomsday94/CyanogenMod-10.1-ariesve

Comment: The codename is ariesve

Comment: https://github.com/CastagnaIT/android_device_samsung_ariesve

https://github.com/skywalker01/android_device_samsung_ariesve

https://github.com/erik96/platform_manifest